# Window not appearing for some third party application such as vscode, intellij idea etc

Tags: gui, 22.04, appmenu

I installed a fresh Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and install VS code and other essential application but I cannot use them, the application are showing in the dock but the GUI is not showing/opening
[co](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jYz5.jpg)

I can see the application in the task switcher also, but the GUI window is not opening. Help, I cannot do my basic day to day work

[Terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55RZE.jpg)
This is the output which I got in the terminal

Comment: why the 14.04 tag if you're using 22.04?

Comment: can you try launching from a terminal (`code` in terminal for vscode) and [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1420695/edit) your question to include the output you get? also how did you install the applications?

Comment: Yeah, I tried to launch code from terminal also but it had the same problem. I installed vscode from snap

Comment: can you post output from terminal? did it print anything in the terminal at all when trying to run?

Comment: Now I installed KDE plasma and all the application are working fine.

Comment: This might be a result of Wayland being the default on 22.04.  There are a lot of applications that just don't work with Wayland - snap or otherwise - that get stuck in Wayland's extra security features.  So you may have to go back to Xorg instead of using Wayland.  There's several questions which address how to do that here on Ask ubuntu